# ReduceLRonPlateau keeps decreasing LR across multiple models

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback, learning-rate

I'm using `ReduceLROnPlateau` for multiple experiments, but I'm getting lower and lower initial learning rate for each conjsecutive modewl run.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ReduceLROnPlateau


for model in models:
    reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.2, patience=10)
    model.fit(dataset, epochs=10, validation_data=val_dataset, callbacks=reduce_lr)
```

The learning rate on the output log looks as follows:

```
Model #1
  Epoch 1  ... lr: 0.01
  ...
  Epoch 21 ... lr: 0.005

Model #2
  Epoch 1  ... lr: 0.005
  ...
  Epoch 25 ... lr: 0.001
```

and so on. (don't look at the numbers I've siplified the output)

How do I tell the model or to the callback to start from the same learning rate each time?

Comment: This state is saved on the callback object, so the obvious solution is to use a different callback instance for each training run.

Comment: Actually I'm creating a new instance each iteration (I've fixed the snippet)

Comment: You are probably using the same optimizer instance for all models.

Comment: Yep, I was using the same model, all over again, but your answer helped to find that. Thanks.